# How to create a set of views dynamically according to API response React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm working on a react native application and the requirement is to create a list of views to display the booked time slots and the free slots in two different colors. The API response gives only the booked time slots. So is there a way to display a chart like a timetable to this scenario.

I have tried the following code to get the outcome. But failed.

```
componentDidMount() {
    return fetch("https://XXXXXXXXXXX.com")
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then((responseJson) => {
            this.setState({
                isLoading: false,
                dataSource: responseJson
            }),
            function () {
                this.arrayholder = responseJson;
            }

            renderCard = () => {
                return (
                    <View style={{ backgroundColor: 'red', 
                                   height: 100, 
                                   width: 100 }}>
                    </View>
                )
            };
        })
        .catch(error => console.log(error))
}

renderItem = (data) =>
    <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={() => {
            this.props.navigation.navigate('OfferDetails');
        }}
        style={{ borderWidth: 2, 
                 borderColor: '#02539D', 
                 height: config.deviceHeight * 0.15, 
                 justifyContent: 'center', 
                 marginLeft: config.deviceWidth * 0.05, 
                 width: config.deviceWidth * 0.9, 
                 borderRadius: 10 
        }}
    >
        <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
            <View style={{ flex: 0.35 }}>
                <Image style={{ height: config.deviceHeight * 0.12, 
                                width: config.deviceWidth * 0.3 
                             }}
                       source={images.durdans_logo}>
                </Image>
            </View>
            <View style={{ flex: 0.65 }}>
                <View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'red' }}></View>
            </View>
        </View>
    </TouchableOpacity>

render() {
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <SafeAreaView>
                <ScrollView horizontal={'true'}>
                    <View style={{ width: config.deviceWidth }}>
                        <ScrollView 
                            vertical={true} 
                            style={{ marginTop: config.deviceHeight * 0.03, 
                                     marginLeft: config.deviceWidth * 0.05, 
                                     marginRight: config.deviceWidth * 0.05   
                                  }
                        >
                        <FlatList
                            data={this.state.dataSource}
                            ItemSeparatorComponent={this.FlatListItemSeparator}
                            renderItem={
                                item => this.renderItem(item)}
                                enableEmptySections={true}
                                style={{ marginTop: 10 }}
                                keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()
                            }
                        />
                        </ScrollView>
                    </View>
                </ScrollView>
            </SafeAreaView>
        </View>
    );
}
```

Is there a way to build a solution for this scenario. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have access to all the available possible time slots? If so, then maintain a data structure (which allow fast indexing) with all the time slots. In the `renderItem` function run an `Array.map` over all the time slots and check if that time slot is available in the `data` argument or not and return the desired component accordingly. I hope it made sense. Also, sharing the sample response will help to understand the scenario better.

Comment: API respond with booked data. I want to add Views for those data with one color and for the time slots which have no records in API response with different color. Do not know whether it is possible

Comment: Ok, got your issue. `FlatList` calls `renderItem` for every item in data. So, basically, you have to manipulate your data before passing it as a prop to `FlatList`. Here what you can do. Assuming your data is an array of objects with possibly a key as 'time'. Now, you need to add dummy objects for all the remainder timeslots and then in your renderItem function just check whether the object has any particular key or not and use a simple ternary operator to switch between two types of component you want.

Comment: I'll try this. It may help. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of rendering only booked time slots, render all the slots, and show it as booked or not.

eg:

```
renderItem = (data) =>
   data.booked?
    <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={() => {
            this.props.navigation.navigate('OfferDetails');
        }}
        style={{ borderWidth: 2, 
                 borderColor: '#02539D', 
                 height: config.deviceHeight * 0.15, 
                 justifyContent: 'center', 
                 marginLeft: config.deviceWidth * 0.05, 
                 width: config.deviceWidth * 0.9, 
                 borderRadius: 10 
        }}
    >
        <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
            <View style={{ flex: 0.35 }}>
                <Image style={{ height: config.deviceHeight * 0.12, 
                                width: config.deviceWidth * 0.3 
                             }}
                       source={images.durdans_logo}>
                </Image>
            </View>
            <View style={{ flex: 0.65 }}>
                <View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'red' }}></View>
            </View>
        </View>
    </TouchableOpacity>
   :
    <Text>Not Booked</Text>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. But the API response only gives the booked time and data. Want to go through response data and should be able to display a timetable of 24 hrs to indicate free times.

Comment: then add empty time slots manually, check for each time slots check if it is in the response and create a new data set with all time slots

Comment: I'll try with your suggestion. Thank you.